# Remove folder if it contain less than two files

Tags: matlab

I have a lot of folders containing .fig files. Some of these folders contains more than one file which is what I want. The others that only contain one file should get removed with a script.

I thought I could (somehow, I am totally fresh) iterate trough the folders (which exists in one folder will all this other folders) and check if the dir contains more than one file, if not: `rmdir(folderName)`.

Is this possible? Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible through MATLAB

```
directoryName = 'folderName';
contents = dir(directoryName)
if length(contents) <= 1
    rmdir(directoryName);
end
```

You can also iterate through multiple directories with

```
files = dir('./');

dirFlags = [files.isdir];

subFolders = files(dirFlags);

for k = 1:length(subFolders)
    directoryName = subFolders(k).name;
    contents = dir(directoryName);
    if length(contents) <= 1
        rmdir(directoryName);
    end
end
```

You should probably check that the subFolder is not `.` or `..`